# Is reading and writing to the same file thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I have one file named "data.txt".

I have two threads.

The first thread, read the entire content of the file:

```
while(1){
    char buf[1000];
    FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
    while(fread(buf,1,1000,fp)>0){
        /* process data */
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The second thread append data to the file:

```
while(1){
    FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt","a");
    fwrite("hello\n",1,6,fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Is reading and writing in this case (WHITOUT any MUTEX or FILELOCKING) are Thread Safe ? (no segmentation fault, etc...)

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe POSIX only specifies operating system interfaces, not the C Library. So if fwrite and fread are thread-safe POSIX doesn't know. It DOES specify that read() and write() are thread safe.

Comment: I doubt you'll crash, but I also doubt that the data your reading-thread reads from the file will be particularly well-defined.  In particular, if you're hoping that the file will behave like a FIFO pipe (where every byte that thread 2 writes is later read, in order, by thread 1), you're likely to be disappointed.

Comment: Have you tried it? It should be easy to prove its not safe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. On windows and Fedora, there is no segmentation fault at all. So I think it is thread safe...

Comment: no segmentation fault didn't mean thread safe.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: POSIX does define the C standard library: e.g. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/fread.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, most standard library functions, among them all but the explicitly unlocked I/O functions, are officially thread safe. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/flockfile.html states explicitly that flockfile() is not needed except for special demands.

A remark about the *unlocked* functions, which are not thread safe, is interesting:

> These functions may safely be used in a multi-threaded program if and only if they are called while the invoking thread owns the ( FILE *) object, as is the case after a successful call to the flockfile() or ftrylockfile() functions.

This implies that the thread safety guarantee of the normal, *locked* functions is stronger than what you are doing: They are safe even when using *the same `FILE` pointer* (the result of *one* `fopen()`). It's easy to see how concurrent updating of the bookkeeping information in a `FILE` struct could corrupt it; the normal standard library functions guarantee not to.

On the other hand the C standard says: "Whether the same file can be simultaneously open multiple times is also implementation-defined." There is [CERT advisory](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO24-C.+Do+not+open+a+file+that+is+already+open) to avoid that. This is your use case of more than one `FILE` struct, obtained by two `fopen()` calls, potentially without an intervening `fclose()`, to the same underlying physical file.

That the standard makes this implementation defined may reflect (potential) limitations of certain operating systems.

A remark on the side: Trying a concurrent algorithm successfully a few times is **not a guarantee that it is correct.** Concurrency issues are ghastly beasts which raise their heads in a non-predictable fashion.

Answer (score 2):

`fread()` and `fwrite()` are inherently **not** thread safe.  They are not likely to cause your program to crash, but the order that reads and writes are made is not guaranteed.

You must use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` if you intend to use them concurrently.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please can you answer to my other derivated question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367231/is-reading-and-writing-to-the-same-file-at-different-bytes-range-thread-safe

Comment: Sure? Cf. the links in my post.

Comment: They are thread safe.  Thread safety does not imply anything about the ordering of the operations.

Comment: You are mistaking thread-safety (e.g. using mutex) with synchronization (e.g. using monitor):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)