# Is reading and writing to the same file at different bytes-range thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, file, concurrency, posix

I have one file named "data.txt" with always 50 bytes of data.

I have two threads.

The first thread, read content from byte 0 to byte 50:

```
while(1){
    char buf[50];
    FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
    fread(buf,1,50,fp);
    /* process data */
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The second thread, append data to the file (= always after the first 50 bytes):

```
while(1){
    FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt","a");
    fwrite("hello\n",1,6,fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Is this solution thread-safe and portable ? (no segmentation fault, no data inconsistency, ...)

Comment: It's not safe unless you can guarantee that the two areas being written to do not overlap, block-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in your other, related post, to my best knowledge it shouldn't crash. Whether it writes and reads and reads properly I don't know.

If you are on a POSIX system: Have you considered using a fifo (cf. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)? I have the impression that the file system is just a helper for your underlying communication demand, i.e. the actual file is not important.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one position indicator associated the file stream, the problem is if you open the file in append mode, the position indicator go to the end of file before every write. You can reposition the position indicator with `fseek()` for reading, but as soon as you write to the file, the position indicator goes back to the end of file.

**EDIT:**
It's OK since each file descriptor in each thread will be independent from each other.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have understand that this is a normal behavior that "hello\n" are appended multiples times. If we do not consider this problem as a problem, is the code thread-safe (no segmentation fault, reading for the first thread always working and returning the good data, etc...) ? Thanks.

Comment: It's not guaranteed every time it works as you expect. If the write last for a time during which `fread()` get called, it would not return the good data.

Comment: I don't understand why the good data cannot be returned by the fread because the first 50 bytes are fixed at the start of the program, and there is two different FILE pointer with two different internal pointer.

Comment: my fault, I thought you share the FILE pointer between the threads. It should be OK.

Comment: It would be better to share the FILE between threads and synchronize its use.  Then you would be assured that overlapping blocks would not cause a problem.